# How can tracking sent emails of users by console app (C#)

Tags: c#, smtp, imap, pop3

Work on the .Net application that tracks the user and makes sure that he doesn't send any work-related information or files that contain work-related data.
So I need to track the sent mail like knowing the receiver, read the body of the message, and check the attachments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Europe, take care, this is forbidden. People can't track emails even professional ones without a judge decision.

For answering your question, which tool does the user use ? If he is using an online email interface (gmail, hotmail, ...), you will probably not be able to do what you want.
If not, then it depends on the tool he is using (Outlook, ...)

Comment: actually, I wish to detect all mail servers such as (Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo, or etc).
about the legality of the matter, the terms and conditions will require the user to agree to that.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do that then. The only wait would be to filter everything that goes through your professional network and even then the datas would most often be encrypted (SSL). If people have to connect through your VPN, you may have this possibility but it wouldn't be easy to check everything. 
So apart from a keyboar logger (which could not check files) I think you can't do what you are asking for.
The problem is that the SMTP request isn't made from your guy's machine but from the google/hotmail/... server.

Comment: And care, even if people sign a condition saying they are ok with that, if they go by the law, you may still lose cause it is something really sensitive

Comment: Ok, I understand.
Thank you for your time and, and your advice.